# Set value of choice field based on input from people picker

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, jquery, form

I have  Choice Field which i use to filter items within a list. I'm trying to figure out a way to set value of this choice field within my edit form is there is a name in the people picker field.

This is my form: [image]
What I'm trying to do is when a NAPA User is selected (any user) the status goes from New to In Progress.

This is what the choice field looks like in consol:

```
<select name="ctl00$m$g_0537f4e9_69aa_409a_b5ed_15e3624efeab$ctl00$ctl05$ctl01$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$DropDownChoice" id="ctl00_m_g_0537f4e9_69aa_409a_b5ed_15e3624efeab_ctl00_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice" class="ms-RadioText">
    <option selected="selected" value="1. New">1. New</option>
    <option value="2. In-Progress">2. In-Progress</option>
    <option value="3. Completed">3. Completed</option>
    <option value="4. Cancelled">4. Cancelled</option>
</select>
```

I got these ID's also:

```
people picker ID: <div id="ctl00_m_g_0537f4e9_69aa_409a_b5ed_15e3624efeab_ctl00_ctl05_ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_UserField_upLevelDiv" 

$("[id$=UserField_upLevelDiv]")

status ID: id="ctl00_m_g_0537f4e9_69aa_409a_b5ed_15e3624efeab_ctl00_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice" 

$("[id$=DropDownChoice]")
```

I just don't know how to write an if statement that would read like:

```
if [$("[id$=UserField_upLevelDiv]")> 0]{
      set.$("[id$=DropDownChoice]").value = 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add content editor web part on newform.aspx page and write jquery ready function and add below code.

ex:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
$("select[title='Status']").val('2. In-Progress');
});
</script>

**for geting current value :** <br><br>

var mySelectValue = $("select[title='My Choice']").val();


**for setting Choice value :**<br><br>

$("select[title='My Choice']").val('2. In-Progress');
```